# Change in date format while using power Automate

Tags: powerbi, power-automate

I m using power automate to export table from power bi to a csv file. But the date format in columns is getting changed.

The following is my power automate workflow that i m using.

[image]

The following is the date format that it is exporting
2024-05-30T18:30:00.000Z
But i need this format instead.
31-may-2024

I have tried changing the format of date in power query but it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time you are receiving is in UTC and you can convert it to your standard time using `convertFromUtc()` method. It takes in 3 parameters:

```
convertFromUtc('<timestamp>', '<destinationTimeZone>', '<format>'?)
```

You can refer to the documentation here for more details:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#convertfromutc

Comment: The date is in a column in the csv file. How do I approach to format the date in the csv file itself?

Comment: You can read the csv and then rewrite the csv.